# Compute divergence of matrix-vector product $A\nabla u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, elliptic-operators

what is the best approach to compute $\text{div}(A\, Du)$ where $Du$ is the gradient vector of a scalar function $u:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ and $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix?

The entries of $A$ are functions defined over $\Bbb R^n$ as well. Do you simply do the same as you would if the expression was $\text{div}(Du)$? Cant think of anything else, but it becomes extremely cumbersome when I am supposed to show that its equal to zero (I have an expression for both $u$ and $A$ but I dont think they are needed to give an answer to my question).

$A$ is symmetric and the associated differential operator is elliptic, in case that should be useful, but I primarily want to know the general approach.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is scalar, then its gradient $\nabla u$ is the vector $[\nabla u]_{j} = u_{,j}$, where indices after the comma indicate partial differentiation. Using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), the product $b = A\, \nabla u$ is the vector $b_{i} = A_{ij}\, u_{, j}$. The divergence of $b$ is the scalar
$$
\text{div}(A\, \nabla u) = b_{i,i} = [A_{ij}\, u_{, j}]_{,i} \, .
$$
The product rule then gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{div}(A\, \nabla u) &= A_{ij,i}\, u_{, j} + A_{ij}\, u_{,ij} \\
& = (\nabla \cdot A^T)\cdot \nabla u + A : \nabla\nabla u \, .
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the symmetry property $A = A^T$ then gives
$$
\text{div}(A\, \nabla u) = (\nabla\cdot A) \cdot \nabla u + A : \nabla \nabla u ,
$$
where the colon denotes the Frobenius inner product.
In the isotropic case $A = \alpha I$, we recover the [vector calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) identity $\text{div}(\alpha \nabla u) = \nabla\alpha\cdot\nabla u + \alpha \Delta u$. By the way, the present problem may be viewed as a particular case of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625185/418542).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I probably misformulated. u is not vector valued, so the gradient is a vector. I meant that R^n is the domain of u. I apologize for confusion.

Comment: @shakmalak answer edited accordingly

Comment: @EditPiAf Under the same hypothesis, and when $A$ is a constant real matrix, did you know please if we can write $div (A \nabla u)$ withe the help of the curl operator ? (I want to find an identity like the $\nabla\times\nabla\times=\nabla\nabla\cdot-\Delta$)

Comment: @SAKLY Dunno if such a thing exists (and how it could be useful)